# Countdown timer to a date set from admin panel

Tags: javascript, php, timer, admin, countdown

I am trying to make a countdown timer that will countdown to a certain date and time.
I would like to be able to set the date and time from a 'admin panel' by typing in the date and time(ex `2014-01-25, 15:00`) in a textbox or something similar.

As you might've figured, I'm not the best at PHP or JavaScript and I'm in need of directions as of how I would do this.

Any help is appreciated as I haven't made any progress in the last 2 hours I've tried doing this.

Comment: Show what you've come up with in your 2 hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this with no frameworks like JQuery, you can do the following:

```
var MINUTE_IN_MILLISECONDS = 60 * 1000;
var HOUR_IN_MILLISECONDS = 60 * MINUTE_IN_MILLISECONDS;
var YEAR_IN_MILLISECONDS = 24 * HOUR_IN_MILLISECONDS;

var targetDate = new Date('2014-01-25 15:00');
var countdownInterval;

function countdown(){
    var currentDate = new Date();

    var difference = targetDate.getTime() - currentDate.getTime();

    //Countdown has expired, cancel interval and do other tasks here
    if(difference <= 0)
    {
        difference = 0;
        clearInterval(countdownInterval);

        //Update button here
    }


    var days = Math.floor(difference / YEAR_IN_MILLISECONDS);
    difference -= days * YEAR_IN_MILLISECONDS;

    var hours = Math.floor(difference / HOUR_IN_MILLISECONDS);
    difference -= hours * HOUR_IN_MILLISECONDS;

    var minutes = Math.floor(difference / MINUTE_IN_MILLISECONDS);
    difference -= minutes * MINUTE_IN_MILLISECONDS;

    var seconds = Math.floor(difference / 1000);

    console.log(days + ":" + hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds);
}

countdownInterval = setInterval(countdown, 1000);
```

Here's the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eRJyt/4/)

Comment: You know there is a thing in computer science called [`mod`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) right...

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 This is simply a straight forward and easy to read example of implementing a countdown.  It's not wrong, just different than your answer.

Comment: Woah I never said your's wrong. I was only suggesting `%` would be a simpler solution for you to use instead of calculating all the remainders.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 Performance of divide and subtract is better than modulus.  [Comparison](http://jsperf.com/modulo-vs-divide-and-subtract)

Comment: Actually, in Chrome 33 modulus is faster than subtract due to internal optimizations. (As you can see from your jsPref starting from Chrome 32.) Using modulus also help increase readability if you are going to revisit the code later on.

Comment: Thank you for this. I managed to use this and make so I can add the time from the admin panel.

I've got one more thing though, when the countdown hits zero I want it to automatically change attribute of a button. Bascially doing an action once the countdown hits zero. Any help with this is greatly appreciated. 

and again, thank you for your help already.

Comment: @user3233471, updated my answer to include when the countdown reaches 0.

Comment: That's great. I've got it to work the way I wanted it aswell as been going through the code and I've learned some new things which I'm sure  will come in handy in the future. I'd like to thank you Preston for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Full demonstration: <kbd>**http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/T48SL/**</kbd>

```
<form>
    <input type="date" required><input type="time" required>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
<span></span>
```

```
$("form").on("submit", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var date = $("input[type=date]").val(),
        time = $("input[type=time]").val(),
        targetTime = new Date(date + " " + time),
        interval = setInterval(function () {
            $("span").html(
                (((+startingTime - Date.now()) / 1000)|0) + " seconds left until " + startingTime.toString() + "."
            );
        }, 500);
});
```

It is fairly easy to format the time instead of just seconds with Algebra:

```
//yourTime is in seconds
(yourTime) % 60            //seconds
(yourTime / 60 |0) % 60    //minutes
(yourTime / 3600 |0) % 24  //hours
(yourTime / 86400 |0)      //days

/*
 *  Explanation:
 *   %  is mod, it finds the remainder of two numbers.
 *   |0 is binary OR, it rounds down a floating number.
 *
 */
```

With this technique, you do not need to do a bunch of subtraction and create a lot of junk variables in the process.